# how to gain access of vector elements for mathematical use?

Tags: c++

newbie programmer here.

I have a vector with double values in it.

```
vector<double> P = {205.65,205.7,205.5,205,203.65,200.70...}
```

now I want to store the difference between two random element in a separate container.
I don't want a loop, there is no order in subtraction. I just want to know how can i subtract one element from another element and store the result in a different container.

Comment: Exactly the same way as for non mathematical use.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, `Q.push_back(P[i] - P[j])` is one way.

`Q` is a container (e.g. `std::vector<double>`) that supports `push_back`.

`i` and `j` are `size_t` types within the range of your vector `P`. `P[i]` is accessing the `i`<sup>th</sup> element of `P`. Note that the indexing starts at 0.

Finally, note that `i` and `j` need to index valid elements of the container: if they are outside the container's range then the program behaviour is *undefined*. Quite often that can be a silent effect insofar there is no immediate runtime failure, but it can have potentially hazardous consequences such as overwriting values of adjacent variables in memory! Some programmers therefore sacrifice a little performance and use `P.at(i)` in place of `P[i]` as the former is required by the C++ standard to throw an exception if an out-of-range access is attempted.

Comment: Does such a low-level question really worth the answer?

Comment: @SergeyA: I enjoy plucking an answer out of the mental fog of a question like this.

Answer (score 1):

Let us say you want difference between the elements at positions i and j.

Step 1: Let us define a new 2D vector using the following statements:

```
      vector <double> diff2(P.size());
      vector < vector <double> > diff(P.size(),diff2);
```

Note that: diff [i] [j] will hold the value of P [i] - P [j];

Step 2: Now enumerate the vector diff as:

```
      diff[i][j] = P[i] - P[j];
```

Note that: i and j are the indices of the elements you want to subtract. The indexing starts from 0.

Example: diff [1] [3] = P [1] - P [3] = 205.7 - 205 = 0.7

Comment: you can do your entire creation of the vector in a single line `vector<vector<double>> diff(P.size(),vector<double>(P.size()));`